# An academic who died over 70 years ago still has Google Scholar profile with verified email. How can this be?

Tags: google-scholar, death

I'm surprised to see that an academic who died over 50 years ago has a Google Scholar profile with a verified email (https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=5qvdHjQAAAAJ):

[image]

How is that possible? I see the email domain, melipona.org, is some online shop.

Comment: On a more serious note, Google seeded Scholar manually with several famous historical scientists ([Albert Einstein](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qc6CJjYAAAAJ), [Isaac Newton](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=j2MGGBAAAAAJ)), although these are listed with "no verified email".

Comment: @ChristianClason Why is Newton's affiliation MIT, which was founded a century after he died?

Comment: Not just any online shop.  It's an online _honey_ shop, and the guy was an expert on bees.

Comment: I assume somebody is playing a joke on an automated system; presumably, somebody whose last name is "Newton" (and whose first name begins with "I") is working at MIT...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Verified email just mean that the user has done the confirmation in his/her inbox. It means in that case that the person that created this profile has an email with the domain "@melipona.org".

Usually, people will do this verification with their institutional email, adding credence that this is the right person, but technically, anyone within an institution can do it for anyone else inside that particular institution.

Comment: So this would appear to be an exceptionally obscure form of search-engine optimization spam?

Comment: That's amusing at least, given that he died almost half a century before people started to get email addresses on a larger scale. The person who confirmed his email address might have thought this amusing as well.