# If you no longer have your university email address does your Google Scholar Profile become invalid?

Tags: google-scholar

Google Scholar requires a university email address for verification. I have not signed up for the service yet. If I leave the university, does my Google Scholar profile become invalid? Or can I still use/update my Google Scholar profile? Can someone post their personal experience about this?

Comment: Apparently a .org address works too, even if you died >65 years ago. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61689/an-academic-who-died-over-50-years-ago-still-has-google-scholar-profile-with-ver

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a google scholar profile for more than 5 years now and was never asked again to verify my account after the initial verification was completed. I can still edit and update my profile as usual.

Comment: Are you still in academia? Or have you moved to industry, etc?

Comment: I just finished with academia