# Where can I find the number of citations the top x % of researchers of a given research field have received?

Tags: citations

I wonder where I can find the number of citations the top x % of researchers of a given research field have received. I'm still specifically interested in the following two research fields: natural language processing and computer vision.

(No self-infatuation intended: I received some third-party request, but I'm fully aware of the numerous bibliometric pitfalls.)

Comment: This will be sensitive to how you decide to count the total # of researchers in a field. I don't believe there is a clear place to draw the line between who counts and who doesn't.

Comment: This will also be sensitive to how citations are counted.  Every platform yields a different number, in part because every platform indexes different subsets of publications.  (I just checked seven different platforms for my own citation record.  I got seven different numbers, the largest of which was more than three times larger than the smallest.)

Comment: @DavidKetcheson true but the method to draw the line is likely field-independent, so at least it'll keep its comparative usefulness. One way is simply to count as researcher anyone with at least one publication.

Comment: @JeffE good point, ideally let's use all publications to count citations

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Right, but what counts as a "publication"?  Review/survey article?  Conference proceedings paper? Unrefereed workshop abstract?  PhD thesis?  Master's thesis?  Research monograph? Textbook?  arXiv preprint?  PDF on ResearchGate?  Patent?  Github repository?  Popular press book?  [Graphic novel?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logicomix)  Blog post?  YouTube video?  Wikipedia article?

Comment: @JeffE let's say a peer-reviewed paper.

Comment: That's a imperfect but reasonable restriction.  But what exactly counts as a "peer-reviewed paper"? I have peer-reviewed review articles, textbooks, and chapters of research monographs; do those count? Most computer science conferences are peer-reviewed, but are you sure you can tell which are not? What about papers published in Chinese in Chinese-only journals? What about papers in predatory journals? (And who decides if they're predatory?) Journals with editorial scandals? Journals that have only published their first issue? Et cetera. There are tons of tiny decisions and no ground truth.

Comment: @JeffE Good points. we'll have to live with some approximations and whatever is available :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Web of Science](https://login.webofknowledge.com/) (paywalled).

Search by the topic ("natural language processing"). You'll reach a page with, as of time of writing, 30,348 results. You can now sort the papers by authors (in the left-hand panel), and select the top x% researchers that way. Then you pick the author at the bottom of that x%, find only the papers by him/her, and generate a citation report.

As of time of writing, there are 62,594 authors. I'm not going to download all the data, but Web of Science makes it possible to display the top 500 of them. The 500th-ranked author is JIMENEZ-LOPEZ MD, which a quick Google search finds is [this professor](http://www.romaniques.urv.cat/ca/llengua-espanyola/8/maria-dolores-jimenez-lopez). Web of Science gives her h-index as 4, number of times cited as 59, and the number of citing articles as 44.

If you need help with operating Web of Science, feel free to ask your librarian.

Comment: Thanks, great to know!

Answer (score -1):

[Monsteriah](https://www.reddit.com/user/Monsteriah) [suggested](https://redd.it/o8jpgc)
to search by keyword on Google Scholar: this indeed allows us to get some decent estimate of the number of citations the top x researchers  in a given research field (defined by a Google Scholar keyword such as "[computer vision](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:computer_vision)" or "[natural language processing](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:natural_language_processing)").

---

Examples:

- The #2000 researcher in [computer vision](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:computer_vision&after_author=bWJDACiD__8J&astart=190) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210627171544/https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Acomputer_vision&after_author=rhcAAMPx__8J&astart=9990), [mirror 2](https://archive.ph/g1Ptn)) has received 3620 citations.
- The #2000 researcher in [natural language processing](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:natural_language_processing&before_author=ecWn_88nAAAJ&astart=1990) ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210627171543/https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Anatural_language_processing&after_author=Q6pqAAr8__8J&astart=1990), [mirror 2](https://archive.ph/as8kR)) has received 1005 citations.

Note: while it is very tempting to manually change the "astart" parameter
in the URL [https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:natural_language_processing&before_author=ecWn_88nAAAJ&**astart=190**](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:natural_language_processing&before_author=ecWn_88nAAAJ&astart=190), this doesn't work and the result is misleading: the pagination will change but the display authors won't. One has to also change the parameter "after_author".

Limitations:

- [I don't know whether there is a way to retrieve the number of researchers with a given keyword on Google Scholar](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/170453/452) so this may not allow us to find the number of citations the top x % of researchers of a given research field have received.
- It is very tedious to look at top 2000 researchers or more because once has to scroll down and click for each 10 researchers due to the current Google Scholar user interface.
- It requires the authors to have a Google Scholar provide. Most do, at least in the computer science researchers who are [alive](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61689/452), but not all. I believe it also requires that the authors have indicated keywords.

---

Screenshot of the keywords in a [Google Scholar profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=UZ5wscMAAAAJ):

[image]