# How can I see the number of Google Scholar profiles that have a given keyword?

Tags: google-scholar

One may specify some keywords in one's Google Scholar profile, [e.g.](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=UZ5wscMAAAAJ):

[image]

How can I see the number of Google Scholar profiles that have a given keyword? E.g., the number of Google Scholar profiles that have a given keyword "[computer vision](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:computer_vision)" or "[natural language processing](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=en&mauthors=label:natural_language_processing)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible.

You'll find this python code very handy for this challenge: https://github.com/WittmannF/sort-google-scholar

You will be able to identify keywords, and rank your results (e.g. by citations/year).

If the Captcha process gets in the way, use this workaround:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-easily-bypass-recaptchav2-with-selenium-7f7a9a44fa9e

Good luck.

Comment: Great info and cool username, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One cannot see the number of Google Scholar profiles that have a given keyword, unless willing to click on the `>` button to go to the next 10 profile links for as many times as need to reach the last page  (> 1000 times). One may encounter some human verification box from Google as well on the way.